# Passing ArrayList of custom objects from Activity to fragment GSON serialization vs Parceable

Tags: android

As the title says, for passing an arraylist of custom object from an Activity to a Fragment, which would be the better approach in terms of performance and all, Using GSON to serialize as a JSON and or implement Parceable interface on the Custom Object? I know Parceable is fast but i don't know if its overkill if you have a complex object structure.

Comment: see my answer in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117687/passing-jsonobject-to-another-activity-via-intent/27118992#27118992

Comment: same way in order to interact with activity to fragment or fragment to activity, you have to pass the values through bundle.